# How do I create DNS entries for private addresses on AWS?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, internal-dns

To do any ops work on our servers, we first need to ssh into a DMZ server with a public IP, before ssh-ing on to the app servers, with ips such as 172.16.3.239. I would rather have memorable hostnames, to do something like `ssh app.staging`, but I am unsure how this works on AWS. I have only setup DNS for globally accessible ips with my registrar, and since the AWS private subnet is for a private range of addresses, this will not work, of course.

I am also sure if I can use any random hostname (that does not clash with a "real" public hostname), or if it would need to resolve to something that would be globally unique (outside of my private subnet).

Comment: Nothing about the DNS prevents you from creating address records with RFC1918 addresses. You do it the same way as any other address record.

Comment: So you are suggesting I just create the dns entries with my local provider? That's fine. But is it possibly to create dns entries in AWS that are "short-hand", like `app-staging` that would only apply in AWS when I ssh around?

Comment: If you have a small number of servers it would be easier to put them in your hosts file, but that won't scale to many servers / operations staff.

Comment: Have you looked into a private hosted DNS zone and Route53 Resolver?

Comment: @Tim Might well be the most cost/time effective solution :D

Comment: @OscarDeLeón No. Or more like: this is Greek to me. I am not very well versed in AWS infra. What do you mean by "private hosted DNS zone"? Like setting up BIND myself?

Answer (score 0):

Two options are:

- [AWS Route 53](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide) is a hosted DNS service. Create a hosted zone (DNS service) for your servers with the private IPs. You can also create a [private hosted zone](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html) (private DNS) but then you will need to delegate DNS to the AWS name servers. This is especially useful if you're using load balancers who's IPs change regularly.
- Hard code the server names in your computer(s) hosts files. This won't scale well to large numbers of servers, large numbers of operations staff, or if IPs change regularly

Comment: Not sure about that first option, since the terms were unknown, but I found some context to fill in the blanks: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/hosted-zones-private.html